# Is there a good way to deal with unobtrusive validation's seemingly asynchronous behavior?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have the below abbreviated validation code running on the submit of a form. Unobtrusive validation is set up for my form.

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";

    $("#feedbackForm").submit(function () {
        var t = $(this).serialize();
        var val = $(this).validate();
        console.log(val.errorList.length);
        return false;
    });
})();
```

When I hit a breakpoint in Chrome, I see the following behavior:
[image: Unobtrusive validation behavior]

You can see from the console that when the code originally executed, it recognized 0 errors in the validation's error list, but when I pause execution via a breakpoint, it recognizes 4 errors in the validation's error list. Also, after the first time, the correct number of errors is correctly calculated at runtime.

- How is this possible?
- How can I obtain the correct number of errors at runtime?

---

#### Edit 1:

I can't reproduce this issue on jsfiddle, so there must be something else going on.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peter_majeed/xf7K4/1/)

---

#### Edit 2:

I must also note that using `setTimeout()` within the submit handler gets the correct result on the second time everytime, but this only seems to corroborate what mattytommo mentioned in his answer.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for said validation plugin? It probably has success and failure callbacks.

Comment: @KevinB: I'm not aware of any documentation for the validate.unobtrusive plugin, but as you can see from tag info, it's something that ships with ASP MVC. I'll see if I can't dig anything up.

Comment: This seems to cover it pretty well: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/539167/Modify-jQuery-validation-settings-using-MVC-unobtr

Comment: @KevinB: I can get the desired results on jsfiddle, so the code I posted should be correct, but there must be something else going on in my project that's causing this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately I'm not sure why measuring the number of errors manually doesn't work, but in the end, all I really want to do is validate the form and do something based on its state, and to accomplish that, Darin Dimitrov's advice works:

[How to check that the unobtrusive validations has been validated in jquery function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238320/how-to-check-that-the-unobtrusive-validations-has-been-validated-in-jquery-funct/8238421#8238421)

I thought for sure I had tried the `valid()` method, and it didn't work, but I suppose I hadn't. Also, it would appear that the unobtrusive plugin favors this method in time over the other two.

#### Working code:

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    
    $("#feedbackForm").on("submit", function () {
        var t = $(this).serialize(),
            val;

        val = $(this).validate();
        console.log(val.numberOfInvalids());
        console.log(val.errorList.length);
        console.log($(this).valid());       
        
        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[image: Validation]

#### Working fiddle

The fiddle worked in the original case, so there's no need to update it.

Comment: Nice. Funny because before I had written my method, I started with .valid() check to make sure it had finished before checking the errors, but then I couldn't work out how to get the number of errors, so I went for mine. Go ahead and accept your answer :) +1

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `validate` you could use the synchronous `invalidHandler` check. That way you know it has completed.

The reason it probably works in your Fiddle is probably coincidentally because it's quicker to validate the form, but slower in your actual implementation.

Try something like this:

```
$("#feedbackForm").submit(function () {
    var t = $(this).serialize();
    $(this).validate({
        invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors) {
                if (validator.errorList.length > 0) {
                    for (x=0;x<validator.errorList.length;x++) {
                        console.log("\n\u25CF " + validator.errorList[x].message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

   $(this).validate();

    return false;
});
```

Comment: What you said about why it works in the fiddle makes perfect sense. (I edited the code for a missing brace, primarily). But unfortunately, nothing was logged to the console using this method, and I didn't see a clear way to get the number of errors. (This may be a moot point, in the end, because I think I may have stumbled upon a solution.)

Comment: @PeterMajeed Thanks for the edit. Hmmm, number of errors should be `validator.errorList.length`. Ah cool, is the solution using mine or another solution?

Comment: Will post in a few minutes! But it is the standard solution.